# How to convert to pure text?

Tags: php

Is there a function or library to detect the format of a text and convert it to pure text? (example utf8) without any other formatting.

Because I have a textarea and an user can copy and paste, example: MS WORD text, or RTF or any other format.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Damiano

Comment: It should lose all formatting by default unless you are using some JS editor on that textarea.

Comment: how does the text/markup look like which you want to convert?

Comment: @markus normal text without any particular formatting...a simple ASCII or UTF8 text.

Comment: so you want to convert normal text to normal text?

Comment: If you've "UTF-8 text" with just ASCII characters like a, b, 1, 2, ., ..., you should name it "ASCII" and you're done. You cannot keep characters like Greek, Chinese and other UTF-8 characters because it does not fit in the ASCII character set.

Answer (score 0):

If your input area is a plain-text one, this should happen by default.  If it isn't, the answer may depend on the platform.  It's often the responsibility of the application where the data came from to format it according to the requirements of the target, so as long as the input text area is requesting the paste as plain text, well-behaved producers of the data should do the formatting during the paste operation.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, it's not clear what you mean by pure text. You can use the mb_convert_encoding function to convert the text to a specific encoding.

```
$str = ...

$str = mb_convert_encoding($str, 'ASCII');
```